# If row exists then update else update

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen this question all over stackoverflow, yet no matter which way I do it, I can't seem to make it work at all. Let me start off by showing my code

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT 1 FROM mybb_tnybracket WHERE tid = '$id' AND player1 IS NOT NULL AND player2 IS NULL");
if (mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $query23 = $db->query("UPDATE mybb_tnybracket SET player1 = '$uidgt' WHERE tid = '$id'      AND player2 is NULL AND player1 is NULL ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1;")or die(mysqli_error());
    echo "update player 1"; 
} else {
        $query22 = $db->query("UPDATE mybb_tnybracket SET player2 = '$uidgt' WHERE tid = '$id' AND player1 IS NOT NULL AND player2 IS NULL LIMIT 1")or die(mysqli_error());
echo "update player 2"; 
}

}
```

Here is quick preview to my database:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/1a2049d4a24f73bc8de3e0be84e98ec8.png]

As you can see player1 and player2 is both null. However, once I use my code, it should update player 1 first. Then my if statement is fetching for any tables where player 1 has a value and player 2 is still null, so then it can fill in player 2. However, this does not happen, all I get when I try to register is the text "update player 2" yet nothing happens. Can anyone help?

Comment: $result = $db->query("SELECT 1 FROM mybb_tnybracket WHERE tid = '$id' AND player1 IS NULL AND player2 IS NULL");

Answer (score 0):

If i haven't misunderstood what you 're trying to do, I think a simple query

```
$result = $db->query("UPDATE mybb_tnybracket SET player1 = '$uidgt',player2 = '$uidgt' WHERE tid = '$id' AND player2 is NULL AND player1 is NULL");
```

will work fine.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm trying to do. I can't fill them all at once because the database is user dependent. Meaning when the first user signs up he gets updated in the column player1, and whenever the second user signs up he gets updated in the column player2 in the same row. However, when a 3rd person signs up, he will update to player1 in a new row. Sorry if it's confusing...

Comment: I see the problem now. I think the most convenient way is to insert a new row every time a new player signs up if there is no column with null in player2 and update the row with the new value in column player2 if there is null value in column player2. Why do you need to hold null values which hold no information?